# Puppeteer js eval function returning an object of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Currently I have the following partial code in my puppeteer file:

```
  const getImgSrc = await page.$eval('#ldpGallery', el => el.getElementsByTagName('img'));
  console.log(getImgSrc);
```

The html I'm getting this from is this:

```
<img data-src="https://example.com/981489624/e132d90154bc6cbc6616442c0742fc43l-m0xd-w1020_h770_q80.jpg" class="owl-lazy" src="">
```

The results I get in my console is this:

```
{ '0': {},
  '1': {},
  '2': {},
  '3': {},
  '4': {} }
```

I'm trying to access data-src from the above html.
After I retrieve the object I tried.
forEach() and map and they both give me an error.

How would I get the data-src string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach is trying to solve everything all the data fetching on the evaluate. You could do something like this:

```js
const getImgSrc = await page.$eval('#ldpGallery', el =>
    Array.from(el.getElementsByTagName('img')).map(e => e.getAttribute("data-src")));
console.log(getImgSrc);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

Your code is not working, because [page.$eval](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) only allows to return serializable data (data which can be [stringified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description)). You are trying to return a HTMLCollection with five DOM elements, which will be serialized to empty objects.

#### Solution

You are trying to read the `data-src` information from all `img` elements inside the `#ldpGallery` element. I recommend you use the function [page.$$eval](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) for that, which is able to work on a list of elements. That way you can directly map the elements and access the `data` attributes via the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) property.

The code then looks like this:

```js
const getImgSrc = await page.$$eval(
    '#ldpGallery img',
    imgs => imgs.map(img => img.dataset.src)
);
```